# Building Autotools for Android

Tags: android, gcc

Perhaps some of you are aware that there is an Android port of GCC 4.7.

I've tested it and it works perfectly, however when 'make' and 'configure' are out of the picture, it is rather useless.

What would it take to port Autotools, including make and configure to Android itself?

If you are wondering who in the world would develop on a phone, you are forgetting that some tablets run Android, though I myself have a phone.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it for android? Maybe it's just working.

Answer (score 1):

make require nothing, but C library and shell; configure is actually shell script, produced by autoconf, which in turn depends on awk, m4 and diffutils. The hardest part is using autoconf and make with Android built-in shell, which is said to lack lot of functionality. Fortunately Android ports of bash already exist.

The most problematic part with porting GNU programming stack to Android is undocumented file hierarchy (device vendors tend to modify it on every whim) and severely lacking Bionic library. There is number of projects, trying to work around this issues (such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/droidoverlay/, for example), but generally this area is still to be explored.

Comment: gentooandroid.sourceforge.net comes with m4, awk, diffutils, gcc, ... It is alpha stage and as a delay of one year on these tools.